# Convert string to unicode in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode, type-conversion, ascii

How can I get the unicode values (from the `code` column) if I have the string?
For example, for passing the empty space " " I would like to get the value `U+0020`.
I found this approach:

```
byte[] asciiBytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(" ");
```

But this returns me the value from the `decimal` column.

[image]

Comment: You mean you want the string `"U+0020"` ?

Comment: ASCII is *not* unicode

Comment: A `string` consists of `char`s, which you can cast to a `short` (or `int`). This will give you more characters than ASCII (which has codes from 0 to just 127). But then you may run into "surrogate pairs" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `value` is your decimal value:

```
string code = $"U+{value.ToString ("X4")}";
```

will give you what you want.

(X means hex, 4 means pad to 4 digits)